# Kmeans for a data matrix containing both dense and sparse columns?

Tags: clustering, k-means, sparse

Assume the matrix contains one dense column, which consists of continuous values between 1-100. The other columns are binary values and are sparse. When applying Kmeans to such as matrix, does the clustering tend to be dominated by the dense columns? What if I want to avoid such domination and also take the sparse columns into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **preprocess** your data.

If one attribute is 0-100, the maximum squared deviation is 10000.
For a binary variable, the maximum is 1. So the influence of the first is way larger than the second.

Properly normalizing mixed data is likely impossible. Whatever you get out, it is biased by your choices in preprocessing, and others may get completely different results.